# Zindex images on SlideShow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I have a slideshow programed here that i want two images to be on top of eachother in the slideshow.

For some reason they are next to eachother and not on top of one another. I want the tag to be on top of the banner in this slide show as i specified here in my slideshow. For some reason they are just appearing next to eachother in the slidse and i cant figure out why?

Here is a link to the example which im having issues with.

I am using this script http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx

http://syndicatebox.com/test/

```
<style type="text/css">
.banner{
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
}
.tag{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 60px;
    left: 59px;
    width: 788px;
    height: 554px;
}
</style>
```

Basically the border image is supposed to be under the restaurant image but they are appearching next to eachother and i dont want to use a whole png image because of the size it takes up.

You can see what i mean here http://syndicatebox.com/test/

Comment: They should expand together as well

Comment: What's the name of the plugin?  What is the relevant HTML code?

Comment: Im using this 

http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx

Comment: BTW:  You have an inline style that sets the `.gallery` element to 800 pixels wide.

Comment: All relevant follow-up information should be edited into the original question.

Comment: Thats because i took it straight out of ym actual website let me include this in the question

Comment: From the Mead plugin page, _"The inspiration for this plug-in this iTunes album viewer."_.  How exactly is this supposed to work like the iTunes viewer if you only show one image at a time?  It defeats the whole purpose of a carousel style plugin.  Maybe you just need something like the [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin for simple transitions from image to image?  If I'm making the wrong assumptions, it's because your question is pretty unclear in describing what you want.

Comment: I need somethign that works just like this. Let me rephrase my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.back{
position:absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 60px;
    left: 59px;
    width: 788px;
    height: 554px;
    padding: 20px;
    backgroung:url(backgroundframe.jpg);
}

</style>

<div class="back">
<img src="image1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
```

Comment: But how can i have the background image under the main image with this?

Comment: I am trying to get the restauraant image over the border image working in the slideshow

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that to the style css. i edited it, have a look at it. by the way you must set theimage file names, i have just used sample names.

Comment: Okay understood let me know! I am so lost after hours